# Not able to fetch current latitude and longitude in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am new in android and i am trying to get my current location latitude and longitude and for this i am using '**com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0**' and i am getting this error
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GoogleApiClient parameter is required**.
and i referred to previous stckoverflow answers but it didnot helped me.Please help me, thanks in advance

and here is the code of Mapsactivity.java

```
   public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity{

   private GoogleMap mMap;
AppLocationService appLocationService;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLastLocation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
   setUpMapIfNeeded();
} 

  private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (mMap == null) {

        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) 
          getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();

        if (mMap != null) {

            displayLocation();
        }
    }
}
private void displayLocation() {

    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

        Log.d("result", latitude + ", " + longitude);

    } else {

      Log.d("result2","(Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is
   enabled on the device)");
     }
 }
}
```

And here is the code of my manifest file

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.malli.myapplication" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission  
 android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" 
/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Do post the whole error logs.

Comment: You are getting the error probably because `mGoogleApiClient` is not initialize - meaning that you are passing null to the `.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);` call which expects instance of `GoogleApiClient`  as parameter.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla after intialising i am not able to see the latitude or longitude in my logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have not initialized your `mGoogleApiClient` variable. please intialize it first.

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();

 mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
```

*Note : this is just a sample to initialize GoogleApiClient*

Comment: After adding the above piece of code it solved that error but in my logcat i am not able to see the latitude or longitude and i am getting these errors in my console

Comment: **E/CardSyncManagerImpl﹕ onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}**

Comment: **I/Finsky﹕ [1] com.google.android.finsky.c.l.a(270): result=false type=4**

Comment: Please consider accepting the suggested answer here (resolved the `IllegalArgumentException` issue) and then posting a related question on the error you are now getting (`API_UNAVAILABLE`).